# How do I scrape this website such that the candidates are classified by list?

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape the following website into a csv file with all the MP candidates, by party and district:

https://www.eleicoes.mai.gov.pt/legislativas2005/be_ftp.html#viana

I've managed to create a loop to go through the different urls for each party. Now, what I want is to scrape all the  name tags, such that each of them will have the associated district - `<td class="ligacoes">` and/or `<span class="ligacoes">` - and party - `<td class="ligacoes">` - in front of each candidate, in the final csv file.

I'm struggling to write a loop that organizes the data as I intend to - the final csv should have three columns, for the candidate's name, district and party. Furthermore, the `<td>` and `<span>` tags have some overlapping information (Beja, Braga, Bragança and Coimbra are in both tags), and I'm also not sure on how to deal with it.

Any advice and/or useful links would be highly appreciated.

```
url = 'https://www.eleicoes.mai.gov.pt/legislativas2005/be_ftp.html#'

uClient = urlopen(url)

list2 =['be', 'cdu', 'cds', 'ph', 'pnd', 'pnr', 'pctp', 'pous', 'pda', 'psd', 'ps']

c = soup.findAll("td", {"class": "bckgrd"}) #candidate and position tags
d1 = soup.findAll("td", {"class": "ligacoes"}) #districts 1
d2 = soup.findAll("span", {"class": "ligacoes"}) #districts 2

# sobreposição de Beja, Braga, Bragança e Coimbra

for i in list2:
    url = 'https://www.eleicoes.mai.gov.pt/legislativas2005/{}_ftp.html#'.format(i)
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
    print(soup)
    #code by page
```

Comment: What content on the page denotes the party?

Comment: It's the text of <td colspan="10" class="ligacoes" valign="middle" height="102" align="left">

Comment: ignoring the _suplentes_ ? i.e. only the _candidatos_ ?

Comment: Yes, without the "suplentes"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can get the relevant `tr` entities and use a generator:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests, itertools as it
def get_page(district):
   d = list(filter(lambda x:x != '\n', soup(requests.get(f'https://www.eleicoes.mai.gov.pt/legislativas2005/{district}_ftp.html#viana').text, 'html.parser').table.contents))[7:-2]
   new_d, last, c = [[i.find('td', {'class':'ligacoes'}), [[k.text for k in b.find_all('td')] for b in i.find_all('tr', {'valign':'bottom'})]] for i in d], None, []
   for a, b in new_d:
      if a is None:
         c.extend([j for _, j in b])
      elif last is None:
         last = a.text
         c.extend([j for _, j in b])
      else:
         yield {'name':last, 'vals':c}
         last, c = a.text, [j for _, j in b]
   yield {'name':last, 'vals':c}

result = [{'name':i, 'party':'be', 'district':k['name']} for k in get_page('be') for i in k['vals']]
```

Output:

```
[{'name': 'Lúcia de Fátima Oliveira Arruda', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Açores'}, {'name': 'Maria de Fátima Diniz Drumond', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Açores'}, {'name': 'Mário Manuel de Castro Moniz', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Açores'}, {'name': 'Mário Miguel Ferreira Lopes', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Açores'}, {'name': 'Delfina Maria Cosme Soares', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Açores'}, {'name': 'Eugénio Paulo \r\n            Martins Viana', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Açores'}, {'name': 'Eulália Maria \r\n            Santos Bendito', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Açores'}, {'name': 'Andrea Luis Valente Rodrigues de Castro Peniche', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Aveiro'}, {'name': 'Pedro Filipe Gomes Soares', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Aveiro'}, {'name': 'António de Oliveira e Silva', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Aveiro'}, {'name': 'Patrícia Carla Flor Veiros', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Aveiro'}, {'name': 'António José Nunes Teixeira Lopes', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Aveiro'}, {'name': 'Paula Jorge Matos de Barros', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Aveiro'}, {'name': 'Rui Jorge de Lima Moreira', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Aveiro'}, {'name': 'Eva Maria Braga da Silva', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Aveiro'}, {'name': 'Vitor Manuel Aguiar Gomes', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Aveiro'}, {'name': 'Maria do Carmo de Pinho Marques', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Aveiro'}, {'name': 'Vanda Maria Seiça Neves Cruzeiro', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Aveiro'}, {'name': 'Vitor Manuel Coelho Valente', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Aveiro'}, {'name': 'Saudade Maria Martins Manso Preto Teixeira Lopes', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Aveiro'}, {'name': 'José Carlos Gomes Lopes', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Aveiro'}, {'name': 'Nuno Filipe Barreiras Pereira Pinto', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Aveiro'}, {'name': 'Carlos Alberto da Silva Veiros', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Aveiro'}, {'name': 'José António Brandão Santos', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Aveiro'}, {'name': 'Maria de Fátima Peixoto', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Aveiro'}, {'name': 'Lino Manuel Teixeira de Jesus', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Aveiro'}, {'name': 'Fernando Manuel Coelho de Sousa', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Aveiro'}, {'name': 'Cláudio Figueiredo Torres', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Beja'}, {'name': 'Lucinda Andrade Elias Correia Pito Simões', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Beja'}, {'name': 'Guida Maria de Jesus Ascenção', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Beja'}, {'name': 'António José Martins Guerreiro', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Beja'}, {'name': 'Maria Cristina Martins Lopes', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Beja'}, {'name': 'Aurelina Florinda de Freitas Rodrigues Lima', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Beja'}, {'name': 'Pedro Manuel Bastos Rodrigues Soares', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Braga'}, {'name': 'José Maria Barbosa Cardoso', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Braga'}, {'name': 'Maria Manuela Barreto Nunes', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Braga'}, {'name': 'José Carlos Sampaio Fonseca', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Braga'}, {'name': 'Adelino Martins Mota', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Braga'}, {'name': 'Maria Custódia Jorge da Rocha', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Braga'}, {'name': 'António Meireles de Magalhães Lima', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Braga'}, {'name': 'João Manuel Machado Oliveira', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Braga'}, {'name': 'Maria João Martins Alves Botelho', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Braga'}, {'name': 'José Manuel Vieira Faria', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Braga'}, {'name': 'Manuel Fernandes da Cunha', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Braga'}, {'name': 'Lisete Carina dos Santos Alvelos', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Braga'}, {'name': 'José Carlos Magalhães da Costa Santos', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Braga'}, {'name': 'Sérgio Adriano Fernandes Lopes', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Braga'}, {'name': 'Maria Manuela Ferreira Ramos Monteiro', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Braga'}, {'name': 'Custódio Manuel de Oliveira Braga', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Braga'}, {'name': 'Mário Jorge Marques da Cunha Pinto Teixeira', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Braga'}, {'name': 'Helena Maria Oliveira Gonçalves', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Braga'}, {'name': 'Manuel António Teixeira da Silva', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Braga'}, {'name': 'Andreia Fernanda dos Santos Ruivo', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Braga'}, {'name': 'António José de Oliveira Cruz Mendes', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Braga'}, {'name': 'Ana Rute Sobral Marcelino', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Braga'}, {'name': 'Luís Miguel do Carmo Rocha Marado Moreira', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Braga'}, {'name': 'Maria da Conceição Nogueiro Gomes', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Bragança'}, {'name': 'Luís Miguel Vale Fernandes Vale', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Bragança'}, {'name': 'António Manuel Couraceiro Léria', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Bragança'}, {'name': 'Marco Paulo Dominguez Mendonça', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Bragança'}, {'name': 'Kevin Charles Rowe', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Bragança'}, {'name': 'João Cristiano Rodrigues Cunha', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Bragança'}, {'name': 'Paula Cristina Barata Monteiro da Costa Nogueira', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Bragança'}, {'name': 'José Serra dos Reis', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Bragança'}, {'name': 'Maria Aline da Silva Gomes Camacho Baião', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Bragança'}, {'name': 'Bruno José Patrício Pereira', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Bragança'}, {'name': 'Fernando Farinha Ferreira', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Bragança'}, {'name': 'Luís Neves Franco', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Bragança'}, {'name': 'André de Matos valente', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Bragança'}, {'name': 'Etelvina Maria Lopes Ferreira', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Bragança'}, {'name': 'Ricardo Pereira Paulouro Neves', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Bragança'}, {'name': 'Manuel Luís Leitão', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Bragança'}, {'name': 'José Manuel Marques da Silva Pureza', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Ana Filomena Leite Amaral', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Luís Carlos Januário Santos', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'António Manuel dos Santos Rodrigues', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Délio Filipe Fernandes de Figueiredo', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Marisa Isabel dos Santos Matias', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'José Barreto Roque', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'João Paulo Águas Tomé Ferreira dos Santos', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Bruno Daniel Gomes de Sena Martins', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Ana Flor Pereira Neves', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'João Filipe Jordão Viegas', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Catarina Isabel Caldeira Martins', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Ana Filipa Duarte Lopes', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Artur Miguel Antunes Dias', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'António José André e Silva', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Abel Maria Simões Ribeiro', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Amália Maria Marques Espiridião Oliveira', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'João António Gomes Ferro ', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'José Faustino Rebocho do Monte', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Fernando Manuel da Cunha Costa', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Ana Paula Coelho Fernandes', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'José Manuel Baptista do Carmo', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'João Fernando Guerreiro Romão', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Maria Manuela Reis Raposo Fernandes', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Vidal da Conceição Marreiros', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Vitor Manuel Bexiga Ruivo', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Henrique Manuel Jerónimo Cabeleira', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Ana Isabel Fernandes Guerreiro', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'João Paulo Pestana Fragoso de Almeida', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'António Manuel Silva Pereira', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'João Manuel Duarte Vasconcelos', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Maria Celeste Simões Baeta', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Albano Ramos Ferreira Torres', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Bruno Filipe Bentes Cortes', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Jorge Manuel da Cunha Coutinho Noutel ', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'José Afonso Vieira ', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Rita Gisela Martins de Azevedo', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Mário Alexandre da Silva Loureiro ', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Paula Maria \r\n            Pais Mamede Fonseca', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Tiago João Queimado \r\n            e Silva', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'António José \r\n            da Costa Almeida Matos Godinho ', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Heitor Nuno Patrício de Sousa e Castro', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'José Manuel Peixoto Figueira Henriques', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Maria Luís Roldão Brites Bustorff', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'António Manuel Brito Sequeira Mendes', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Adelino António Moreira Granja', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Maria João da Fonseca Casaleiro Franco Teixeira', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Joaquim Gil Sousa Piló', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Fernando António da Costa Rocha', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Ana Isabel Pereira da Costa Bernardes', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'João Maria Filipe', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Pedro Sousa Nogueira Antunes', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Celina Marques dos Santos', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Gabriel da Silva Ferreira', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Marília Inês Rodrigues Canhoto', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Paula Cristina Pereira Marques Conceição', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Francisco Anacleto Louçã', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Luís Emídio Lopes Mateus Fazenda', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Ana Isabel Drago Lobato', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Helena Maria Moura Pinto', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Diana Marina Dias Andringa', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Daniel João Figueiredo de Oliveira', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Maria Cecília Vicente Duarte Honório', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'António Vieira Grosso', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Paulo Aníbal de Oliveira Fidalgo', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Maria José Vitorino Gonçalves', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'José Manuel Marques Casimiro', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Leonor Cintra Mattos Gomes', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Miguel de Matos Castanheira do Vale de Almeida', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Ana Ribeiro Cruz', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Gil de Oliveira Garcia', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Maria Helena Augusto das Neves Gorjão', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Miguel Afonso da Silva Ribeiro Reis', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Jorge Emanuel Gomes da Silva', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'João Pedro Amaral Cabouco Rodrigues', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Heloísa Maria Pereira Perista', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Natasha Carmen de Santana Nunes', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Miguel da Câmara e Almeida Pinto', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Vitor Edmundo Proença da Silva', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Maria Alfreda Cordeiro da Cruz Ribeiro Viana', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Maria do Céu da Cunha Meneses Fazenda', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Fernando José de Abreu Matos', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Maria João Lopes Freitas', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'João Carlos Gouveia Pascoal', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Dina Maria Veredas Nunes', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Maria Manuela Monteiro da Silva Fonseca', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Maria Teresa Alves Sousa de Almeida', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'André Aurélio Marona Beja', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Ana Rita Teles Patrocínio Silva', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Luís Carlos Betencourt de Matos Leiria', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Carolina Maria Portela Cardoso', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'António Manuel Candeias Coelho dos Santos', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Vitor Manuel Rodrigues Brilhante', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Rita Susana Borges Cortez Folgosa', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Sérgio Magos Jorge de Sousa Vitorino', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Raquel Cardeira Varela', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Gonçalo Magos Jorge de Sousa Vilarinho', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Francisco José de Jesus Oliveira Raposo', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Isabel Maria de Sousa Lopes de Faria', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Helder Manuel Monteiro', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': "Rita d'Ávila Cachado", 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Tiago Gillot Faria', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Rita Maria Oliveira Calvário', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Isabel Maria Sousa Pinto Allegro de Magalhães', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Mara Madalena Lopes Correia', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Mário José da Silva Fonseca', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Berta Maria Bessone Ferreira Alves', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Ana Paula Ribeiro Aboim Gomes', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Maria do Céu Lopes Maia Cadete', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Roberto Carlos \r\n            Teixeira Almada', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Rodrigo Nuno \r\n            Pontes de Gouveia Trancoso', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Joana Maria \r\n            Vieira Martins', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Ana Paula Rodrigues', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'José António \r\n            Abreu Santos', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Cláudia Vanessa \r\n            Fernandes Gonçalves', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Ana Maria Gouveia \r\n            Gonçalves', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Eduino Narciso \r\n            de Araújo Aguiar', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Mário Camacho \r\n            de Sousa', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Carla Susana \r\n            Silva e Freitas Cardoso', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Fernando Dinarte \r\n            Almada de Gouveia', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Bruno Sousa \r\n            Jardim ', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Paulo José da \r\n            Rosa Cardoso', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Joana Rosa Palmeiro \r\n            de Deus', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Maria Germana Frazão da Silveira de Carvalho', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'José Luís Peixoto', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'João Miguel Trancoso Vaz Teixeira Lopes', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Alda Maria Gonçalves Pereira Macedo', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'João Pedro Furtado da Cunha Semedo', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Alda Maria Botelho Correia de Sousa', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'José Borges de Araújo de Moura Soeiro', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Maria de Fátima Félix Pereira Grácio', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'José Manuel Machado de Castro', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Maria da Conceição de Oliveira Carvalho Nogueira', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Gonçalo Manuel Lemos dos Reis Torgal', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Jorge Duarte Chaves Magalhães ', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Ana Luísa Ribeiro Barata do Amaral', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Maria José de Sousa Magalhães', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Alberto de Sousa e Silva', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Maria Cecília Peixoto da Eira', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'João Paulo Rebelo da Silva', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Fernando José Leite de Oliveira Queiroz', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Hugo Manuel Mota Cardoso da Silva', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Tiago Barbosa Ribeiro', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Armando Herculano Lopes Ferreira', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Maria Esmeralda Correia Mateus', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Eduardo Augusto Ramos Valdrez', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Joaquim Manuel Monteiro Espirito Santo', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Catarina Príncipe Leal Azevedo Fernandes', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Paulo Fernando Teles de Lemos e Silva', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'José Alfredo Carneiro Teixeira Viana', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Joaquim dos Santos Pinho', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Ana Paula Santos Pereira Sequeiros', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'António Alcino Norte Simões ', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Bruno da Cruz Maia', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'António Teixeira Gomes', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Pedro Jorge Teixeira Ferreira', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Maria Elisa de Carvalho Antunes Magalhães', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Tiago Filipe Pereira Brandão de Pinho', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Francisco Amorim Santos Baptista', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Isabel Maria de Sousa Hortas', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Paulo Alberto Branco Teixeira de Sousa', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Maria Alice Moreira  Ribeiro dos Santos', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Alexandre Vieira Pinto Alves Costa', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'António Martins Moreira Capelo', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Orlando Deolindo Gonçalves Carvalho', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Luís Eugénio de Oliveira Peres', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'João Joaquim Monteiro Damas', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Paulo Renato Cardoso Ricardo', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Joana Beatriz Nunes Vicente Amaral Dias', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'António Francisco Gomes Lopes', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Pedro Choy de Amélia Cordeiro', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Maria de Fátima Vieira Figueira Roldão', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Fabíola Cruz Neto Cardoso', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Natércia Rodrigues Lopes', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Carlos Alberto Trincão e Conceição', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Guilherme Sarmento Pinto', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Carla Maria Pires Rodrigues', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Ana Patrícia de Campos Bica', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Manuel António Rodrigues Lopes', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'José das Neves Filipe', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Rui Miguel Gonçalves Fernandes', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Carlos Miguel dos Santos Faria', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Luís Filipe Lopes de Freitas', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Fernando José Mendes Rosas', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Mariana Rosa Aiveca Ferreira', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'António Augusto Jordão Chora', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Mónica Orlanda Jeanne Frechaut', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Maria Manuela Paiva Fernandes Tavares', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Mário Durval Póvoa do Rosário', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Luís Artur Ribeiro Gomes', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Almerinda Lopes Bento', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Maria Alice Silva de Brito', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Jaime Manuel Almeida Pinho', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Cristina Maria de Melo Cavalinhos', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Daniel Patt Arruda', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Joaquim Inácio Raminhos Cabaça', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Cipriano José dos Santos Pisco', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'João Manuel Martins Madeira', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Henrique João da Costa Guerreiro', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Ana Luisa Brito Costa Alho', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Igor Alexandre Claro Caldeira', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'António José de Azevedo Albergaria Samara', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Humberto Manuel Coelho Candeias', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Cristina Luisa Nunes Sizifredo', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Maria Filomena Castro Coelho de Oliveira e Sousa', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Luís Filipe de Oliveira Louro', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Fernando António da Silva Marques', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Maria José Braga Cerqueira', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Francisco Ribeiro Vaz', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Paula Alexandra Caravela Barbosa Braga', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Sebastião José da Cunha Torres Correia', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'António Manuel Antas Moreira', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Jorge Manuel Lopes Rodrigues Lima', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Manuel de Sá da Mota', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Rui Rodrigues Marques', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Suplente 5', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Paulo Henrique das Neves Martins Pires', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Miguel Marinho Ferreira Queimado', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Carlos Manuel Moreira Gomes', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Rui Manuel Victor Cortes', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'José Henrique Morgado de Sousa Martins', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Raul Rocha Magalhães Castro Marques', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Ana Sofia Matos Gomes', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Maria da Graça Melo Cabral Marques Pinto', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Carlos Alberto Vieira e Castro Rodrigues', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'José Carlos Costa Vasconcelos', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Joaquim José Tato Fidalgo Freitas', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Patrícia Marques Cardoso', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Carla Maria de Albuquerque Mendes', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Abílio Gomes Travessas', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'António João Loureiro Amaro', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Clara Maria Mendes Pais Alexandre', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Manuela Maria Coelho Antunes', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Bárbara Soares de Oliveira e Sá', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Carlos Alberto do Couto Esteves de Almeida', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Pedro Miguel Marques Cerdeira', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}, {'name': 'Sandra Cristina Miranda Costa Bastos', 'party': 'be', 'district': '-Coimbra'}]
```

Solution to iterate over parties:

```
list2 = ['be', 'cdu', 'cds', 'ph', 'pnd', 'pnr', 'pctp', 'pous', 'pda', 'psd', 'ps']
result = [[{'name':i, 'party':'be', 'district':k['name']} for k in get_page(party) for i in k['vals']] for party in list2]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. The output of the generator, once I've added the loop through the different url's, is the following:
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'table'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

Comment: @JoãoJerónimo What version of Python are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 3.7.4

Comment: @JoãoJerónimo Are you calling `get_page` with `'be'` as the parameter, or another district name?

Comment: 'be' is the party. I wasn't calling get_page, because I've inserted it inside the for loop that i've presented above, that iterates through the parties' pages. Because of the AttributeError, I've tried to define get_page outside the loop, but a syntax error appeared on the 'results' line. I feel like it might have something to do with the brackets [], because it's a problem that i've experienced before, but I'm not sure though

Comment: @JoãoJerónimo Can you post this most recent code sample?

Comment: @JoãoJerónimo Thank you very much. Indeed, your code is also raising that error for me. The issue is that you are repeatedly defining the function inside the loop. I was able to successfully iterate over the parties after defining the function. Please see my recent edit.

Comment: Is the new version of the code meant to be inside the url loop? Because the same syntax error of the results' line continues to appear, both with def in and outside the loop. Everything else appears to be fine. Could it have something to do with the python version?

Comment: @JoãoJerónimo The new snippet is supposed to be run by itself. Since it, as a list comprehension, iterates over over `list2`, you do not need to retain your original `for i in list2:` loop.

Comment: You're right, it finally worked. My mistake! I can't thank you enough. You were a huge huge help.

Comment: @JoãoJerónimo No problem, glad to help!